# Insert Data with URL?

Tags: c#, mysql, url

I have an Url like this:

http://treen.workcloud.at/?tag=answererq&tan=123456789&answer=1&id=1

When i type it into my Browser the tan, the answer and the Id get inserted into a MySql Database. Now I want it to do it in C#, but i do not know how to do it exactly. That is the code I have so far.

```
        string qid = lbid.Content.ToString(); 
        int answer = 1;
        string urla = @"http://treen.workcloud.at/?tag=answereq&tan=" + tan + id + answer;


        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urla);
        //httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `?` in your URL, which is incorrect.  It should be a `?`.  This is the correct URL:

`http://treen.workcloud.at?tag=answererq&tan=123456789&answer=1&id=1`

`?` signals the start of a query string in a `GET` request.

Additionally, since it is a GET request, you should not be setting the Content Type header and you should not be appending content to the request.  Use something more like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://treen.workcloud.at?tag=answererq&tan=123456789&answer=1&id=1");

using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
   using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
   {
       var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

Comment: yes sorry it was a typing error i edited it in my question.

Comment: Since it's a get request, browsing to it should show you the result that you'll get back.  When I browse to that location, I get a form input.  Is it possible that the query is not an acceptable query for that site?

Answer (score 2):

First i think your url is not quite right. To pass parameters, the format should be.

```
string url= www.blahblahblah.com?parameter1=myvalue&parameter2=myothervalue
```

Calling Request.QueryString["parameter1"] retrieves the value in the url that has the name parameter1 so the value returned for

```
 var parameter1 = Request.QueryString["parameter1"];\\equals myvalue
```

second, once you retrieve the values, you can then pass them to your method to update the database

```
var parameter1 = Request.QueryString["parameter1"];
var parameter2 = Request.QueryString["parameter2"];
//check if the querystring exists
if (parameter1 != null && parameter2 !=null)
{
    UpdateDatabase (parameter1, parameter2);
}
```

You may need to add the system.web namespace. See the MDSN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: yes sorry it was a typing error i edited it in my question.

Comment: but how i can prefer to my url in your Code?

Comment: And i do not want to insert fixed data in the database. The data that should be poste comes from labels etc.

Comment: the code unfortunately do not work. I get the error that request has no definiton for querystring.

Comment: Ive updated my answer, perhaps the link to the documentation will help.

Comment: Ok thank you i will try, but I have another question. Is there a possiblity to use a string for example that i have posted in my question string answer = 1 or a content in a label instead "parameter 1" ?

Comment: The code is also not work with the system.web namespace

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easiest way to get the values from the url, why not read them from the querystring. E.g.:
`string tanValue = Request.QueryString["tan"];`
`string answerValue = Request.QueryString["answer"];`
`string idValue = Request.QueryString["id"];`

Comment: I want to insert them not to get them.